# text file to dictionary as keys

Tags: python

How can I convert file's words to dictionary as it's keys, directly, without using the list? Here is my code:

```
def abc(f):
    with open(f, "r")as f:
        dict = {}
        lst = []
        for line in f:
            lst += line.strip().split()
        for item in lst:
            dict[item] = ""
    return dict


print(abc("file.txt"))
```

Example of input "file.txt":

```
abc def
ghi jkl mno
pqr
```

Output:

```
{"abc":"", "def":"", "ghi":"", "jkl":"", "mno":"", "pqr":""}
```

The output of split() is a list. So, by use of that I need to read the data from file, store it on a list and then define it as dictionary's keys. My question is how can we ignore the list, and after reading data from file, put them directly to the dictionary?

Comment: Please give a small example of an input file, describe what your code is doing, and what you expected it to do.

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to do, and you described what your code currently does, apart from throw an indentation error.

Comment: don't you want to _count_ the words? why creating a dict without value when you can create a `set` ?

Comment: Since you are not using the dictionary value, why not use a `set`?

Comment: `dict = {}`: bad don't use `dict` as a variable name

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre your one-liner is invalid (should be `{word:"" for line in f for word in line.split()}`) ;)

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers thank you a million times. My answer was wrong (3 people upvoted it...) Well fixed now.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre you're welcome ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you *really* want a dictionary, build it in one go using a dict comprehension on the splitted words:

```
def abc(f):
   return {word:"" for line in f for word in line.split()}
```

but you probably want a `set` instead since there are no values to your dict:

```
def abc(f):
   return {word for line in f for word in line.split()}
```

I suspect you want to *count* the words, in that case:

```
def abc(f):
   return collections.Counter(word for line in f for word in line.split())
```

note that `split` doesn't split on punctuation, so if the text contains some, you'll have duplicate words unless you replace

```
for word in line.split()
```

by

```
for word in re.split("\W",line) if word
```

(using `re` package, which has the slight drawback to generate empty fields at the start / end which is easily fixed by filtering `word`)

Answer (score 4):

I don't know what you're trying to do nor what the expected output really is, but the following is functionnaly equivalent to your code snippet (and a bit cleaner too)

```
def abc(f):
    dic = {}
    with open(f, "r")as f:
        for line in f:
            # using split() will already remove
            # trainling whitespaces so you don't 
            # need strip() here
            for item in line.split():
                dic[item] = ""
    return dic
```

Comment: BTW no need for `line.strip().split()` =>`line.split()`

Comment: Well, from the question and snippet I understand he wants to build a dict of "word"=>"" for all "words" in a text file, without using an intermediary list.  Oh and yes, there IS a need for `split()` if you want to be iso with the OP's code snippet (I assume he has many words per line).

Comment: I meant drop `strip()` not `split()`